# Mysql select using regexp

Tags: mysql, regular-expression, regex

I have some user input i am receiving from some forms exactly in this format `Names#Age#Gender#City`

The problem is,some forms come with incomplete data which is acceptable during the filling of the form which leaves me with data of the form `names#Age` and the rest of the data is not there.

Since there are many records i want first to process the data with all the four fields with data and i want to use regular expressions to select all those complete records first.

I have tried this query

`SELECT text_message from incoming_sms where text_message REGEXP '^([a-z]+$)*[a-z]+$';`

but this does not match what i want.

Comment: What about **`text_message LIKE '%#%#%#%'`**?

Comment: I used this and it works `SELECT text_message from incoming_sms where text_message REGEXP '^([^#\n]+#){3}[^\n#]+$'`. Yours too works,i have tested it,finally.Could you add that as an answer?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how strict you want to be, and on what you can expect from the form.

If all that's needed is the presence of 3 `#`'s, it would suffice to use

```
SELECT text_message
FROM incoming_sms
WHERE text_message LIKE '%#%#%#%';
```

If you want to have at least *one* character in each field, you can use (as you suggested yourself):

```
SELECT text_message
FROM incoming_sms
WHERE text_message REGEXP '^([^#]+#){3}[^#]+$';
```

If you know that leading whitespace is trimmed from each field and you want to ensure you have at least one non-whitespace character, use:

```
SELECT text_message
FROM incoming_sms
WHERE text_message REGEXP '^([^#\s]+[^#]*#){3}[^#\s]+[^#]*$';
```